# request.getparamater not working in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

request.getparameter is not working in my spring mvc i am using html5 below is the code.

i have tried by adding name to the text attribute in the html it did not work.

```
package com.springmvc.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;


public class HelloWorldController implements Controller {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("***************");
    String userName =   req.getParameter("userName");
    String user =   req.getParameter("user");
    String nameCheck = req.getParameter("Username");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("Sucess");
        return mv;
    }

}



  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
      <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
      <button>Register</button>
```

Comment: Have you submitted this form by  method `post`?

Comment: Yes i have tried with post as well it did not work

Comment: Hmm, my bad, what I meant is which method did you chose to submit your form?

Comment: i am using handleRequest method itself and i am not using annotations the control is coming to the controller as well